# Show unwanted coding "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm "

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the below ASPX coding "Not Razor" in MVC3 and get the unwanted code "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm " while run in the view page.

```
<%= Html.BeginForm("ChartFeatures","Chart") %> 
  <div>
     <h3>EXPORT CHART</h3><br />
     Enter file name:<input type="text" id="FileName" name="FileName" value=""/>   
     Type:     
     <select name="Type">
     <option value="Bmp">Bmp</option>
     <option value="Gif">Gif</option> 
     </select><br /> 
     <input type="submit"value="Export"id="submit"/>
  </div>
```

anyone could help me please.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Do you have the complete aspx code? And am i correct that the output html contains "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm"?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you form content in `using` and remove `=`:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("ChartFeatures","Chart")) { %> 

your form content here

<% } %>
```